# How do I use a Fresnel integral C Library in c++?

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

I've included a Fresnel Integral Library (http://www.mymathlib.com/functions/fresnel_sin_cos_integrals.html) in my c++ application.

Assume I have the following c++ code (main.cpp):

```
#include "include/Fresnel/fresnel_sine_integral.c"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile the program like this:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
In function `xFresnel_Sine_Integral(long double)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `xFresnel_Auxiliary_Cosine_Integral(long double)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `xFresnel_Auxiliary_Sine_Integral(long double)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do I have to link the library on another way into my c++ application? Or do I have to compile on another way?

Comment: According to the link you mention, additional c files must be used. Loot at the **source code** section

Comment: Yes I have seen it. Therefore it just downloaded all the files and put them all into the same folder. Do I have to include all the files in main.cpp?

Comment: If these files are not already inlcuded in the first file, then you have to include all effectively.  Another option is not to include any file, but compile separately, create a Fresnel library, and link your main.o with this library. In this last case, you have to create the corresponding .h file.

Comment: Okay, I just tried to include all the *.c file in main.cpp. But this leads me to a lot of other errors (redefinition of ...).

Comment: Difficult to help you without entering details of the files, but this is why not inserting .c files, only .h files, is better generally

Comment: Try downloading all three files, call rename them to `.h` , include all and then try again.

Comment: @WolfgangBrehm I just renamed all the files but I still get an error ( redefinition of....)

Comment: try just including `xchebyshev_Tn_series` and `fresnel_sine_integral` in that order

Comment: If I just include `xchebyshev_Tn_series` and `fresnel_sine_integral` in that order I get the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Then I guess the website gave you shitty source code which you need to fix first, remove the functions so that there is only one definition for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to *make* a library from the C source files you referenced. They aren't sufficiently self-contained as they are.

I would suggest structuring your build to compile the `.c` source files along with your own application sources, and linking the whole lot into an executable. You'll need to extract the function declarations from each of the `.c` files and put them into a `.h` header. You'd `#include` that header in your own source, and probably in the `.c` files unless you want a screen-full of compiler warnings each time you compile.

You'll need to decide whether to compile the `.c` files as ordinary C, or rename them and compile them as C++. You might have to modify them, for a C++ compiler to compile them without complaint. If you keep them as C, you'll need to arrange for these files to be compiled as C, and your own as C++. So the headers you make will need to be compatible with both C and C++ -- there are standard techniques for this, which I could advise on (but there's probably stuff on SO already).

If this were my problem to solve, I'd consider combining all the `.c` files into a single file, and fiddle it to be good C++ (probably not difficult). I'd create one single header from the declarations in the C source, suitable for including in C++ source (since it's all C++ now). However, I'm not sure whether the original files are licensed in such a way to allow this -- that's something I guess you'd need to check with the author.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me a lot. I just created an header and a cpp file. It is running now :-)